# How to create a form with an inline input number within a text sentence?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Hi I want to create a single input inline form in Rails thats within a text sentence. I currently use Simple Form and Bootstrap. My current code displays a normal form:

`= simple_form_for @team do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :event_id
  = f.input :places
  = f.button :submit`

I want it to be like this for the user:

"Create me a team sheet with |Integer input| places" |Create Button|

For example the user may type into the |Integer input| a football team so will enter |11|. I understand I may not be able to use Simple Form for this and it will require pure HTML which is fine.

Cheers

Comment: If i'm right did u want a default value in places text field ?

Comment: Sorry no @sp1rs I've edited the question to explain it better. No a default value is not necessary. I simply want to get a number input from the user but display the input as part of a sentence. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using `form_for` you can do it easily, as below:

```
= form_for @team do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :event_id
  Please create a team sheet with 
  = f.text_field :places 
  = f.button :submit
```

This will create an `inline text field` within the sentence like,

```
"Please create a team sheet with |13| places" |Submit Button|
```

Also, as `places` is a number, you can go for `f.number_field` instead of `f.text_field`.

Answer (score 0):

=simple_form_for @team do |f|

= f.hidden_field :event_id

Please create a team sheet with

= f.text_field :places, label: "places"

= f.button :submit